# Escape characters within an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a specific div that cannot have tags within it.
Whenever tags are found, I would like to escape them and display as regular text.

For example:

```html
<div class='no-tags-div'>
   <h1>Hi!</h1>
   <p>Blablablabalablal</p>
</div>
```

Instead of displaying the `Hi!` as a header text followed by a paragraph of `Blablablabalablal`, I would like to literally display it with the tags:

```
<h1>Hi!</h1>
<p>Blablablabalablal</p>
```

I already have access to the content I just need to figure out how to escape any of these special characters.

Edit: I should probably specify, the content within the div is posted through an input. I am attempting to not allow users to post other tags through the input, so this isn't just static HTML text we are talking about here.

Comment: You can use `element.innerText`.

Comment: To anybody who stumbles upon this, I found the solution by using the follow npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-html. It was deleted for some reason, but I think it is helpful for anyone else who has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to escape `<` and `>`. If you're doing this on the server side, you can find and replace those. On the client, you can use `element.innerText`, as D. Pardal suggested, which replaces the contents of `element` with a text node, rather than interpreting it as HTML.